# Shape data frame by adding zero in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with distance in the first colomn and class in the second:

```
data.tab <- read.table(text = "
644 1
76  1
78  1
350 1 
45  1
37  2
366 2 
46  2
71  3
28  3 
97  3
30  3
55  3 
65  3
116 3  
30  3
18  4
143 4
99  4")
```

I want to shape it into a new data frame by adding zero according to the longest class. The result will be:

```
data.tab <- read.table(text = "
1 644 76  78 350 45 0  0  0
2 37  366 46  0  0  0  0  0
3 71  28  97 30 55 65 116 30 
4 18  143 99  0  0  0  0  0")
```

Comment: I'd take a mix of the solutions laid out here : `data.tab$col <- ave(data.tab$V1, data.tab$V2, FUN=seq_along); df <- spread(data.tab,col,V1,fill = 0)`

Comment: That has 3 disadvantages: it overwrites `data.tab`, it repeats `data.tab` three times and it adds dependencies.

Comment: indeed, but very readable, and the 2 formers are easy to solve : `. <- data.tab; . <- ave(.$V1, .$V2, FUN=seq_along); df <- spread(.,col,V1,fill = 0)`. I think this wins the code golf too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `df` as name instead of `data.tab`:

```
MAX <- max(table(df$V2))
t(sapply(split(df$V1, df$V2), function(x) c(x, rep(0, MAX-length(x)))))
```

(The idea is to split V1 into groups defined by V2, making the vectors equal in length by adding `0`'s at the end when necessary, and then combining that into a single matrix. `sapply` does the last bit automatically but columnwise, so `t` is needed.)

#### another way using `length<-`

```
U <- unstack(df) # a hack learned from G.Grothendieck's answer
U <- with(df, split(V1,V2)) # more readable version of the above
M <- max(lengths(U))
R <- t(sapply(U, "length<-", M)) # setting all lengths equal 
replace(R, is.na(R), 0)  # replacing NAs by zeroes
```

And a (rather unreadable) one-liner doing the same thing:

```
"[<-"(R<-t(sapply(U<-unstack(df),"length<-",max(lengths(U)))),is.na(R),0)
```

Answer (score 4):

This essentially boils down to a simple long to wide reshape

```
library(tidyverse)
data.tab %>%
    group_by(V2) %>%
    mutate(col = paste0("V", 1:n())) %>%
    spread(col, V1, fill = 0) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 4 x 8
#     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   644    76    78   350    45     0     0     0
#2    37   366    46     0     0     0     0     0
#3    71    28    97    30    55    65   116    30
#4    18   143    99     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) xtabs** Using only base R create a sequence number column within class and then use `xtabs` to rearrange it into a table.  Finally convert that to data frame. Omit the last line of code if a table is sufficient.

```
data.tab2 <- transform(data.tab, seq = ave(V2, V2, FUN = seq_along))
xt <- xtabs(V1 ~ V2 + seq, data.tab2)
as.data.frame.matrix(xt)
```

giving:

```
    1   2  3   4  5  6   7  8
1 644  76 78 350 45  0   0  0
2  37 366 46   0  0  0   0  0
3  71  28 97  30 55 65 116 30
4  18 143 99   0  0  0   0  0
```

**2) ts** Another base R solution is to convert the elements of each class to a `ts` series giving `tt` a multivariate time series with NAs at the ends of the shorter ones.  Convert those NAs to 0 in the second line of code and then convert that to a data frame in the last line.

```
tt <- do.call("cbind", lapply(unstack(data.tab), ts))
tt[] <- ifelse(is.na(tt), 0, tt)
as.data.frame(t(tt))
```

**3)** Using data.tab2 from (1) use `tapply` to create the matrix `mat` and then convert that to a data.frame.  Omit the last line of code if a matrix is sufficient.

```
mat <- with(data.tab2, tapply(V1, list(V2, seq), c, default = 0))
as.data.frame(mat)
```

### Note

A comment claimed `ifelse` would be slower than a suggested alternative but benchmarking it showed no overall difference on the data in the question.  Of course performance may not be very important here in the first place.

```
library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(
  ifelse = {
    tt <- do.call("cbind", lapply(unstack(data.tab), ts))
    tt[] <- ifelse(is.na(tt), 0, tt)
    as.data.frame(t(tt))
  },
  replace = {
    tt <- do.call("cbind", lapply(unstack(data.tab), ts))
    tt[is.na(tt)] <- 0
    as.data.frame(t(tt))
  }
)[1:4]
```

giving:

```
     test replications elapsed relative
1  ifelse          100    0.25        1
2 replace          100    0.25        1
```

Comment: don't use painfully slow ifelse, `tt[is.na(tt)] <- 0`

Comment: See Note at end of answer.

Answer (score 0):

using `data.table`'s transpose

```
cbind(sort(unique(data.tab$V2)),do.call(rbind,transpose(transpose(split(data.tab$V1, data.tab$V2), 0))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,]    1  644   76   78  350   45    0    0    0
#[2,]    2   37  366   46    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    3   71   28   97   30   55   65  116   30
#[4,]    4   18  143   99    0    0    0    0    0
```